# Filtering issue with exchange api for Exchange2010_SP2 version

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, exchange-server-2010

I have two queries to exchange server verion `Exchange2010_SP2`. The first request attempts to get items with AppointmentID (extended property) value equals to a specific value. The code uses the `IsEqualTo` search filter to accomplish this. Here is the c# code.

- Single filter request

```cs
var timeZone = TimeZone.GetFromName("Eastern Standard Time");
var id = "2a1f9fda-84b9-4090-91f0-6b5fc4949f3f";
var calendar = "mycalendar@mailinator.com";
var appointmentIdExtendedProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "AppointmentID", MapiPropertyType.String);

var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2, timeZone.ToTimeZoneInfo())
{
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password"),
   Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
};
var view = new ItemView(10)
{
   PropertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Id, appointmentIdExtendedProperty)
};
var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(calendar));
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(appointmentIdExtendedProperty, id);

var items = service.FindItems(folderId, filter, view);
```

- Combined filter request

This second query is similar to the above, the only difference is that it applies two filters combined with a logical or operator. I am pasting only the filters construction.

```cs
 SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(appointmentIdExtendedProperty, id);
 SearchFilter containsFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(appointmentIdExtendedProperty, id);
 var combinedFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, new[] { filter, containsFilter });

 var items = service.FindItems(folderId, combinedFilter, view);
```

The results of the first request is an appointment the meets the single filter criteria, however the second request returns no results. By definition the second filter should return items that satisfy the criteria of one or more search filters. The second request should return at least the items returned by the first request since it contains the first filter as part of the filter collection.

Here is also the http requests generated from the above c# code:

- First request

```xml
POST https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: ...
Host: outlook.office365.com
Content-Length: 2368
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemId" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="AppointmentID" PropertyType="String" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:Restriction>
        <t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="AppointmentID" PropertyType="String" />
          <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
            <t:Constant Value="2a1f9fda-84b9-4090-91f0-6b5fc4949f3f" />
          </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
        </t:IsEqualTo>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
          <t:Mailbox>
            <t:EmailAddress>mycalendar@mailinator.com</t:EmailAddress>
          </t:Mailbox>
        </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

- Second request

```xml
POST https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: ...
Host: outlook.office365.com
Content-Length: 2728
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemId" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="AppointmentID" PropertyType="String" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:Restriction>
        <t:Or>
          <t:IsEqualTo>
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="AppointmentID" PropertyType="String" />
            <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
              <t:Constant Value="2a1f9fda-84b9-4090-91f0-6b5fc4949f3f" />
            </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          </t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="AppointmentID" PropertyType="String" />
            <t:Constant Value="2a1f9fda-84b9-4090-91f0-6b5fc4949f3f" />
          </t:Contains>
        </t:Or>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
          <t:Mailbox>
            <t:EmailAddress>mycalendar@mailinator.com</t:EmailAddress>
          </t:Mailbox>
        </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there any well known issue with this version of exchange server?

Comment: The second xml has following  [t:Contains] tag which restricts the search.

Comment: @jdweng if the [t:IsEqualTo] is met the [t:Contains] it is also met. In addition both tags are combined by an [t:Or] operator so if an item meets [t:IsEqualTo] it also meets [t:IsEqualTo] or [t:Contains].

Comment: "IF" it matches than you are correct.